# Display information as gadget or winform NotifyIcon?

Tags: winforms, windows-desktop-gadgets

I am going to develop an application which will periodically query against an database and display the most updated scheduler/queue information for their product process.

My initial thought is that a gadget could do that, as the main function is to display information, and that information should be readily available most of the time without user intervention. But it seems that Microsoft discontinued gadget from a little bit reading. Should I worry about that and using winform NotifyIcon instead? It just occur to me that something like gadget is more simple and probably more user friendly due to its simplicity?

Or are there any other options I am not aware of? It will be a simple application to simplify business process, and I think it is safe to assume that  the machine will be Windows 7.

Comment: Consider posting on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'd focus on the current desktop. Since your current target is Windows 7, I wouldn't worry too much about it. It seems quite unlikely that businesses would switch to Windows 8 en masse.

Besides, for Windows 8, you'd presumably want to make some kind of Metro app instead.

Comment: Assume we are talking about Windows 7, and the options will be?